# How to detect mouseenter/mouseleave event on lots of items without slow-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, canvas, mouseevent

I have realy specific question about Canvas handling mouse-events. 
I'm working on a isometric game, I have a displayed map with all tiles, and I want know on which one the mouse are.

On a basic isometric map it's easy to transform the position on the screen (blue on the next image) on a map position (orange) with basic affine function (ax+b, with 'a' is width_tile/height_tile and b is the current position of the map view, red line on the image)..

[image: Basic isometric game]

But I have a complication, each tile of the game have a **specific elevation** (displayed by red arrow on second image). So i can't use a function for each line(y)/column(x) of the map.
On the same technique I'll try to calculate if mouse position are on EACH tile one by one for EACH mouse event (move, click, ..) but I'm afraid for the heavy code : if I have a 100x100 map and I shack the mouse, I'm sure all this test will ruin the client browser..

[image: My isometric configuration]

I realy don't know how can I do it better ?! 
Someone have an idea, or a tips to optimize this check ?

Comment: It's difficult to advise you without seeing code, however I would suggest using a delegated event on a parent element. That way a single event handler will handle all the isometric tiles in your grid.

Comment: I think you need to hold a JavaScript object model representing the tiles structure. Each object will represent a tile. Then when a burst of mouse events coming in you'll be able to do a fast calc. And from that point you'll have the power to draw the best result, depent on the performance

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : I'm sorry but I don't have any code to show. In your case, I'll have an only event handle but for each mouse move i must test all tiles. You don't think it's too heavy ?

Comment: @arik, If I understand, you think it's better to create one object by tile, and one event handler by object. When the mouse move, all object 'll receive the event, and each will test if the mouse are on the tile ? Is that ? But, if the mouse are on 2 tiles (like the second image) ? With the loop on each tile, i can start at bottom and stop on first founded.. :/

Comment: But what I mean is that those objects are JavaScript objects, that contains the data. If you process those objects it will be fast. After that you can activate the real draw that actually render your elements. It means that you save lots of render time.